# Como enviar datos post a laravel desde react?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, reactjs, react-native

Envio mis datos de esta forma:

```
async subirInfo(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.form)//veo si todos los datos estan correctos.(si lo estan)
    try{
        let config = {
            method:'POST',
            header:{
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(this.state.form)
        }

        let res = await fetch(`${url}/api/vehiculo`,config)
        let data = await res.json()

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

La petición se realiza correctamente, pero los datos no llegan al servidor, estoy utilizando `php-laravel` para dicho caso:

Cod del Server:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data=new Vehiculo($request->all());
    $data->save();
    return response()->json($request->all(),201);
}
```

Dicho codigo ocasiona un error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  el valor null para la columna «color» viola la restricción not null
>   DETAIL:  La fila que falla contiene (1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2019-12-07 10:08:52, 2019-12-07 10:08:52). (SQL: insert into "vehiculos" ("updated_at", "created_at") values (2019-12-07 10:08:52, 2019-12-07 10:08:52) returning "id") in file C:\xampp\htdocs\vera\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 664

Y como veran todos los datos estan en null.

Comment: Creo que `JSON.stringify` que usas provoca que el body sea una cadena de texto en vez de un objeto. Es decir recibiriamos "{\"input1\": \"valor\" }"  en vez de {input1: "valor"}. Esto explicaría porque la mayoría de valores para la consulta INSERT SQL sean `null`. Podrías verificar  esta teoría con `var_dump($data);exit();` también eliminando el stringify y nos cuentas :)

Comment: @AngelFragaParodi, tenias razon lo cambie por un FormData, y me funciono correctamente. Pero ahora tengo que hacer una peticion ´put´ y aun utilizando FormData, los datos no llegan, alguna otra sugerencia? Nota:envio una imagen la cual ya añadi a mi FormData.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví a gracias al consejo de Angel Fraga Parodi.

Solucion: Cambiar `JSON.stringify(this.state.form)` por un `FormData`:

```
async subirInfo(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('color', this.state.form.color)
    formData.append('marca', this.state.form.marca)
    formData.append('placa', this.state.form.placa)
    formData.append('tipo', this.state.form.tipo)
    formData.append('nro_interno', this.state.form.nro_interno)
    formData.append('capacidad', this.state.form.capacidad)
    var fileField = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
    formData.append('avatar', fileField.files[0]);
    try{
        let config = {
            method:'POST',
            header:{
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body:formData
        }

        let res = await fetch(`${url}/api/vehiculo`,config)
        let data = await res.json()
        this.setState({
            vehiculos:this.state.vehiculos.concat(data),
            form:{
                color:"",
                marca:"",
                placa:"",
                tipo:"",
                nro_interno:"",
                capacidad:"",
                imagen:""
            }
        })
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: respecto a que con el put no te funciona es porque  el method es siempre post `method:'POST',`  ;)